# Is the independent sum of a continuous random variable and mixed random variable continuous?

Tags: probability

Suppose X is a continuous random variable (has a pdf on the reals), and Y is a mixed random variable (its CDF has atoms). X and Y are independent. Is the sum, Z=X+Y a continuous random variable (i.e., has a pdf on the reals)?

Comment: In thinking about this question I found it useful to contemplate the situation where $Y$ is the most extreme atom possible: a constant.

Comment: In this extreme case you mentioned, the sum is a continuous random variable. In the case when Y is a discrete random variable, the answer is also yes, Z is continuous. I am wondering how general this is.

Comment: The "mixed" case literally is that: it's a mixture of a continuous and a discrete distribution.  Thus, it suffices to develop intuition for the sum of a mixture distribution and another distribution.  The math says the result is a mixture of the sums.

Comment: Is there a reference you can give for this?

Comment: I think you need to be explicit about the independence of $X$ & $Y$ in your question. For example, if $X=C-Y$ for some constant $C$, then it does not matter whether $Y$ is continuous, constant, mixed or discrete.

Comment: Also: Welcome to CV, Guest!

Comment: Thanks, Alexis. Yes, X and Y are independent.

Comment: The general result follows immediately from the [Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem) and the definitions.

Comment: whuber: By the general result, do you mean the original question, or that the mixed random variable can be decomposed into two measures?

Comment: Both, because--as you demonstrated in your first comment--the decomposition is the heart of the matter and everything else is straightforward to show and understand.

Answer (score 6):

There is a relatively elementary demonstration that the sum is continuous.

Let $X$ have a probability distribution function $F_X$ with density function $f_X$ and let the distribution function of $Y$ be $F_Y.$  We do not assume $Y$ has a density function.  **I claim that $X+Y$ has a density function** (implying it is absolutely continuous) and its density can be expressed as an expectation,

$$f_{X+Y}(z) = E[f_X(z-Y)] = \int_\mathbb{R} f_X(z-y) \mathrm{d}F_Y(y).$$

**To prove this claim,** it suffices to show that integrating $f_{X+Y}$ indeed gives the desired probability function for $X+Y.$  The integration is performed by invoking Fubini's Theorem to change the order of the integrals, then changing the variable of integration from $w-y$ to $x,$ and finally expressing a probability in terms of an indicator function $\mathcal{I}.$  The remaining equations are just definitions of distribution functions and expectations as integrals:

$$\eqalign{
\int_{-\infty}^z f_{X+Y}(w)\mathrm{d}w &= \int_{-\infty}^z \int_\mathbb{R} f_X(w-y) \mathrm{d}F_Y(y)\ \mathrm{d}w \\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} \int_{-\infty}^z f_X(w-y) \mathrm{d}w\ \mathrm{d}F_Y(y) \\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} \int_{-\infty}^{z-y} f_X(x) \mathrm{d}x\ \mathrm{d}F_Y(y) \\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} F_X(z-y) \mathrm{d}F_Y(y) \\
&= E[F_X(z-Y)] \\
&= E_Y[\Pr(X \le z-Y)] \\
&= E_Y[E_X[\mathcal{I}(X+Y\le z)]] \\
&= \Pr(X+Y\le z) \\
&= F_{X+Y}(z).
}$$

For some intuition, think of adding $X$ to $Y$ as "smearing" every possible value of $Y$ according to the distribution of $X$ or, equivalently, as using $Y$ to weight a mixture of shifted versions of $X.$  In either case it's clear the result will have no atoms because $X$ has no atoms and so (of course) none of its shifted versions have atoms, either, whence no mixture of them will have any atoms.

[image: Figure]

*In this figure, the left panel depicts the density of $X.$  The next panel shows the* mass *of $Y$ -- this variable has no density.  Nevertheless, as shown in the third panel, adding $Y$ to $X$ produces as many continuous components of $X$ as there are spikes in $Y,$ each one scaled by the height of its spike.  The density of $X+Y$ is the accumulated height of all these components.  Because it is formed from density functions, it too is a density, showing that $X+Y$ follows a continuous distribution even though $Y$ does not.*

Comment: Quick question: integrating $f_{X+Y}$ shows that $X+Y$ is absolutely continuous?

Comment: @Taylor Distributions with density functions are absolutely continuous.  The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus says that when the integral of $f$ is $F,$ then $f$ is the derivative of $F,$ which makes $f$ a density function for $F.$

Comment: Gotcha, so if $X$ and $Y$ are independent absolutely continuous random variables, then $X+Y$ is absolutely continuous with density $f_{X+Y}$?

Comment: @Taylor That is a special case of what I have shown here, because it's unnecessary to assume both $X$ and $Y$ have density functions: only one of those variables has to be a.c. for $X+Y$ to be a.c.